# "vtable" in the dexdump result

Tags: android, assembly, vtable

I'm doing some research on dexdump. Now, there is a question that confuses me. 
when you look at the dexdump result, you will find "vtable" in the code like this:

```
000854: fa20 a900 4300                         |0000: +invoke-super-quick {v3, v4}, [00a9] // vtable #00a9    
00085a: 1500 037f                              |0003: const/high16 v0, #int 2130903040 // #7f03    
00085e: f820 ef00 0300                         |0005: +invoke-virtual-quick {v3, v0}, [00ef] // vtable #00ef    
000864: 1500 057f                              |0008: const/high16 v0, #int 2131034112 // #7f05    
000868: f820 7200 0300                         |000a: +invoke-virtual-quick {v3, v0}, [0072] // vtable #0072    
00086e: 0c00                                   |000d: move-result-object v0
```

Does anybody know what the "vtable" actually linked to? 
Is there any documentation about this?

Answer (score 1):

vtable probably stands for "virtual table".  Its a way of implementing virtual functions (and if you're about to say you're using java due to android being on here, in java all functions are virtual)-  all virtual functions are in an array of function pointers.  So vtable #00a9   Probably means offset 00a9 into the virtual table.